# PHP CURL sometimes returning empty result

Tags: php, curl

I'm having a little inconvenient problem using PHP's curl functions. Below is a brief description of the scenario before moving on to the code.

The Script it's running on command line and is responsible for importing to local database of information coming from a web api.

The class responsible for the web api query performs three steps:

1. Requesting an Azure oAuth token, (this request is working
   perfectly), this token is cached and renewed from time to time
   without major problems.
2. An API query is performed that returns a json containing some
   objects
3. The array returned by item 2 is traversed and used to query another
   API method, which returns another json.

Anyway, I hope you have managed to be clear on the scenario, unfortunately I can not pass on too many details about this API = /

Now, the code, I am using PHP curl functions for access to the API, as I mentioned before, the token works perfectly, the biggest problem is in steps 2 and 3, sometimes the return from step 2 is empty, other times from step 3, no error is ever generated in either curl_error, curl_errno or curl_info (Even in this one the HTTP code generated is 200).

```
<?php
namespace RestClient\Service;

/**
 * Cliente abstrato de acesso ao webservice REST
 * Este cliente é responsável por gerar o token para uso
 * com os demais clientes.
 *
 * @author Rodrigo Teixeira Andreotti <ro.andriotti@gmail.com>
 */
abstract class AbstractClient
{

    private $tokenUrl;
    private $clientId;
    private $secret;
    private $serviceUrl;
    private $resourceId;
    private $tenantId;
    private $apiKey;
    private $cache;

    /**
     * Recebe em seu construtor uma instância da 
     * aplicação rodando e uma do handler de cache
     * 
     * @param \Core\Application $app
     * @param \Core\Cache\Cache $cache
     */
    public function __construct(\Core\Application $app, \Core\Cache\Cache $cache)
    {
        $this->tokenUrl = $app->getConfig('api_token_url');
        $this->clientId = $app->getConfig('api_clientId');
        $this->secret = $app->getConfig('api_secret');
        $this->serviceUrl = $app->getConfig('api_service_url');
        $this->tenantId = $app->getConfig('api_tenantId');
        $this->apiKey = $app->getConfig('api_key');
        $this->resourceId = $app->getConfig('api_resourceId');

        $this->cache = $cache;

        $this->loadToken();
    }

    /**
     * Verifica se existe um token válido em cache, 
     * caso haja o carrega, se não gera um novo token no webservice, 
     * o salva em cache e o retorna para uso pelo serviço.
     * 
     * @uses AbstractClient::requestToken()
     * 
     * @return string Token gerado / armazenado
     */
    private function loadToken()
    {
        $cache = $this->cache;

        $token = $cache->readCache('api_token');

        if (!$token) {
            $tokenData = $this->requestToken();
            $cache->saveCache('api_token', $tokenData->access_token, 45); // <-- Converte o tempo do token para minutos
            $token = $tokenData->access_token;
        }

        return $token;
    }

    /**
     * Requisita ao webservice o token de acesso
     * 
     * @return \stdClass Contém o json decodificado com as informações do token
     */
    private function requestToken()
    {

        $ch = curl_init($this->tokenUrl . $this->tenantId . '/oauth2/token');


        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
            'resource' => $this->resourceId,
            'client_id' => $this->clientId,
            'client_secret' => $this->secret
        ));



        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


        $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));



        curl_close($ch);

        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Realiza a consulta ao webserice
     * 
     * @uses AbstractClient::buildUrlParams()
     * 
     * @param string $method Método REST que será consultado
     * @param array $params Paramentros adicionais que serão chamados
     * 
     * @return \stdClass Retorno do json decodificado
     */
    protected function callService($method, $params = null)
    {

        $ch = curl_init($this->serviceUrl . $method . ($params ? $this->buildUrlParams($params) : ''));


        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);

        // Linhas abaixo necessárias para usar o cUrl com windows sem certificado
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);


        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_HTTPGET => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->loadToken(),
                'X-Api-Key: ' . $this->apiKey,
            )
        ));


        $response = curl_exec($ch);


        $httpCode = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));

        if ($httpCode != 200) {
            return $httpCode;
        }

        $data = json_decode($response);


        curl_close($ch);

        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Constrói os parâmetros em formato de URL
     * 
     * @param array $params
     * @return string Parametros de URL formatados
     */
    private function buildUrlParams($params)
    {

        $urlParams = '';
        if (count($params)) {
            $urlParams .= '?';
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($params as $key => $param) {
                $urlParams .= (($i == 0) ? '' : '&');
                $urlParams .= $key . '=' . $param;
                $i++;
            }
        }

        return $urlParams;
    }

}
```

Since I'm using my own cache solution, my class follows:

```
<?php

namespace Core\Cache;

/**
 * Sistema de cache
 *
 * @author Rodrigo Teixeira Andreotti <ro.andriotti@gmail.com>
 */
class Cache
{

    /**
     * 
     * @var integer Tempo para o cache em minutos
     */
    private $time = 60;

    /**
     *
     * @var string Local onde o cache será salvo
     */
    private $local;

    /**
     * Inicializa a classe e define o local onde o cache será armazenado
     * @uses Cache::setLocal()
     * @param string $local
     */
    public function __construct($local)
    {
        $this->setLocal($local);
    }

    /**
     * Define o local onde o cache será salvo
     * @param string $local
     * @return $this
     */
    private function setLocal($local)
    {
        if (!file_exists($local)){
            trigger_error('Diretório de cache não encontrado', E_USER_ERROR);
        } elseif(!is_dir($local)) {
            trigger_error('Caminho para diretório de cache não aponta para um diretório', E_USER_ERROR);
        } elseif(!is_writable($local)){
            trigger_error('Diretório de cache inacessível', E_USER_ERROR);
        } else {
            $this->local = $local;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gera o local onde o arquivo será salvo
     * @param string $key
     * @return string
     */
    private function generateFileLocation($key)
    {
        return $this->local . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . sha1($key) . '.tmp';
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Cria o arquivo de cache
     * 
     * @uses Cache::generateFileLocation()
     * 
     * @param string $key
     * @param mixed $content
     * 
     * @return boolean
     */
    private function generateCacheFile($key, $content)
    {
        $file = $this->generateFileLocation($key);

        return file_put_contents($file, $content) || trigger_error('Não foi possível criar o arquivo de cache', E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Salva um valor em cache
     * 
     * @uses Cache::generateCacheFiles
     * 
     * @param string $key
     * @param mixed $content
     * @param integer $time Tempo em minutos
     * 
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function saveCache($key, $content, $time = null)
    {
        $time = strtotime(($time ? $time : $this->time) . ' minutes');

        $content = serialize(array(
            'expira' => $time,
            'content' => $content
        ));

        return $this->generateCacheFile($key, $content);
    }

    /**
     * Recupera um valor salvo no cache
     * 
     * @uses Cache::generateFileLocation()
     * 
     * @param string $key
     * 
     * @return mixed Valor do cache salvo ou null
     */
    public function readCache($key)
    {
        $file = $this->generateFileLocation($key);

        if (is_file($file) && is_readable($file)) {
            $cache = unserialize(file_get_contents($file));

            if ($cache['expira'] > time()) {
                return $cache['content'];
            } else {
                unlink($file);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Generally has a specific order to occur the problem, on the first attempt item 2 described above does not work, on the second attempt is item 3 that does not work and on the third attempt works okay. lol

Thank you in advance for the time and help of my colleagues.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I can solve the problem on my own, so I would like to leave the solution I got here if someone else has the same problem.

Apparently the problem was in this code block of the callService method:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);

// Linhas abaixo necessárias para usar o cUrl com windows sem certificado
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);


curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_HTTPGET => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->loadToken(),
        'X-Api-Key: ' . $this->apiKey,
    )
));
```

I could not figure out the exact reason, but I compared it with the code generated by Postman and changed some lines to fit the request to what postman was using, after the changes it looked like this:

```
    // Linhas abaixo necessárias para usar o cUrl com windows sem certificado
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    $token = $this->loadToken();


    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPGET => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token,
            'Cache-Control: no-cache',
            'X-Api-Key: ' . $this->apiKey,
        )
    ));
```

For me, apparently, it solved the problem. Thank you!